# add div id and for attribute sequentially using js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to dynamically add the id and for attribute for each input and label element.

```
  <div id="splash">
    <div class="tab">
      <input id="tab-1">
      <label for="tab-1"><label>
    </div>

   <div class="tab">
     <input id="tab-2">
     <label for="tab-2"><label>
   </div>

   <div class="tab">
     <input id="tab-3">
     <label for="tab-3"><label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

So basically I would want the id for the input to be tab-# with the # increasing by 1 for each input field and the same for the "for=" attribute for the label.

Comment: do you want javascript or jquery? any preference?

Comment: @JonathanChaplin It's tagged jQuery, so I assume that.

Comment: It's also tagged Javascript....

Comment: It's pretty difficult to write jQuery without JavaScript. Since it's tagged both, it seems logical that it would be using jQuery. Not knocking you for asking, of course...

Comment: true, but maybe either was acceptable to the OP. It's not specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's super easy. Just iterate through each `.tab`, using each's `index` argument, and modify the attributes of the elements.

```
$('.tab').each(function (index) {
  var tabName = 'tab-' + (index + 1);
  $('input', this).attr('id', tabName);
  $('label', this).attr('for', tabName);
});
```

Jsbin: http://jsbin.com/rawatag/4/edit?html,js,output

Comment: What is the target parameter here?

Comment: @AakashVerma It's just another way you can get the element, rather than `$(this)`. It doesn't matter which one you use really, unless you're doing arrow functions or weird bindings.

Comment: I guess it should be $('input', this).attr('id', 'tab-' + (++i));

Comment: However, you use `this` as context, so you can remove the unused `target` param.

Comment: @DanielGrankin Nope. The each function automatically increments it.

Comment: Yep, it was asked to show <input id="tab-1"> instead of <input id="tab-0">

Comment: @DanielGrankin Good point- I'd probably go for `i + 1` rather than `++i` to prevent confusion about whether it's mutating

Comment: @MattFletcher yes, I just wrote i++ to show idea and actually it was not correct it works only with ++i inline.

Answer (score 0):

No need for jQuery here:

### es5 ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9v94oxeh/1/))

```
function assignInputsAndLabels(root) {
    var children = root.children;
    var tabNumber = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i].classList.contains('tab')) {
            children[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].setAttribute('id', 'tab-' + tabNumber);
            children[i].getElementsByTagName('label')[0].setAttribute('for', 'tab-' + tabNumber);
            tabNumber++;
        }
    }
}

assignInputsAndLabels(document.getElementById('splash'));
```

### es6

```
function assignInputsAndLabels(root) {
    const children = root.children;
    let tabNumber = 1;

    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i].classList.contains('tab')) {
            children[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].setAttribute('id', `tab-${tabNumber}`);
            children[i].getElementsByTagName('label')[0].setAttribute('for', `tab-${tabNumber}`);
            tabNumber++;
        }
    }
}

assignInputsAndLabels(document.getElementById('splash'));
```

The parameter to the function is the wrapper of the elements that have the class of `tab`. In your case, you'd pass in the DOM node of the element with id of `splash`. So you'd call the function like this:

```
assignInputsAndLabels(document.getElementById('splash'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using javascript.Check it below

```js
function init(){
    
 var sel = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
 
 var i=1;
 
 for(let obj of sel){
          var attr = "tab-"+i;
          obj.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].setAttribute("id",attr);
          obj.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].setAttribute("for",attr);
   i++;
 }
   
 }
 
 addEventListener("load",init);
```

```html
<div class="tab">
 <input type="text">
 <label></label>
</div>

<div class="tab">
 <input type="text">
 <label></label>
</div>
```